# Links from tag edit in a users activity summary don't work

Tags: bug, status-completed, editing, recent-activity

I have noticed that the links shown in [my activity summary](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/440/flow?tab=activity) that belong to a tag edit, excerpt and full tag wiki, [point to non](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14014/bugs-wiki-excerpt)[-existent questions.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14013/bugs-wiki-description)

Is this intended?

Comment: That's definitely broken.  The SE folk should come across this soon and (hopefully) fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug was the result of some related back-end changes, which will be corrected in the next build.  Kinda glad this broke, an even earlier change could be made even faster/cheaper for the wiki-redirect case...and now is.